# Android Calendar picking birthday gives wrong days remaining for one condition

Tags: java, android, performance, calendar, dialog

I have a solution with revising some examples i found online to getting days remaining until birthday, But i have a bug/problem with one condition in my `daysRemaining()` method.

activity.java

```
private Profiles.AgeCalculation age = null; //this is in the class, and not onCreate
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_transition_edit);

    //Age Calculation
    age = new Profiles.AgeCalculation();
    age.getCurrentDate();
}
//includes for age calculation

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DATE_START_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    mDateSetListener,
                    startYear, startMonth, startDay);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        startYear=selectedYear;
        startMonth=selectedMonth;
        startDay=selectedDay;
        System.out.println("Birth Year: " + startYear);
        System.out.println("Birth Month: " + startMonth);
        System.out.println("Birth Day: " + startDay);
        age.setDateOfBirth(startYear, startMonth, startDay);
        //birthDate.setText("Date of Birth(DD/MM/YY): "+selectedDay+":"+(startMonth+1)+":"+startYear);
        //calculateAge();
        //age.daysRemaining();
        calculateYear();
    }
};
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.age_button:
            showDialog(DATE_START_DIALOG_ID);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
    private void calculateYear()
{
    age.calcualteYear();
    age.calcualteMonth();
    age.calcualteDay();
    age.daysRemaining();
    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "click the resulted button"+age.getResult() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    textViewDisplayAge.setText(age.getYearsOld() + " Years Old");
}
```

AgeCalculation.java

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class AgeCalculation {
private int startYear; //birth year
private int startMonth; //birth month
private int startDay; //birth day
private int endYear;
private int endMonth;
private int endDay;
private int resultYear;
private int checkFor16;
private int resultMonth;
private int resultDay;
private Calendar start;
private Calendar end;
public String getCurrentDate() //gets current date of mobile device using Calendar
{
    end=Calendar.getInstance();
    endYear=end.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    endMonth=end.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    endMonth++;
    endDay=end.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    System.out.println("Current Year: " + endYear);
    System.out.println("Current Month: " + endMonth);
    System.out.println("Current Day: " + endDay);
    return endDay+":"+endMonth+":"+endYear;
}
public void setDateOfBirth(int sYear, int sMonth, int sDay)
{
    startYear=sYear;
    startMonth=sMonth;
    startMonth++;
    startDay=sDay;

}
public void calcualteYear()
{
    resultYear=endYear-startYear;
    checkFor16 = endYear-startYear;
    //In this year the user will be this age
    System.out.println("caculateYear: " + resultYear);
    System.out.println("checkFor 16 years old: " + checkFor16);

}

public void calcualteMonth()
{
    if(endMonth>=startMonth)
    {
        resultMonth= endMonth-startMonth;
    }
    else
    {
        resultMonth=endMonth-startMonth;
        resultMonth=12+resultMonth;
        resultYear--;
    }
    System.out.println("calculateMonth: " + resultMonth);

}
public void  calcualteDay()
{

    if(endDay>=startDay)
    {
        resultDay= endDay-startDay;
    }
    else
    {
        resultDay=endDay-startDay;
        resultDay=30+resultDay;
        if(resultMonth==0)
        {
            resultMonth=11;
            resultYear--;
        }
        else
        {
            resultMonth--;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("calculateDay: " + resultDay);
}

public String getResult()
{
    return resultDay+":"+resultMonth+":"+resultYear;
}

public int getYearsOld(){
    return resultYear; //returns the age of the user
}

public void daysRemaining(){

    final String strBDay = String.valueOf(startDay) + "/" + String.valueOf(startMonth) + "/" + String.valueOf(startYear);

    Date example = null;
    DateFormat dateFormat;
    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.US);
    try {
        example = new Date(dateFormat.parse(strBDay).getTime());
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    final Calendar BDay = Calendar.getInstance();
    BDay.setTime(example);

    final Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

    // Take your DOB Month and compare it to current month
    final int BMonth = BDay.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    final int CMonth = today.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    BDay.set(Calendar.YEAR, today.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    if(BMonth <= CMonth)
    {
        BDay.set(Calendar.YEAR, today.get(Calendar.YEAR) + 1);
    }

    long now = new Date().getTime();

    // Result in millis
    final long millis = BDay.getTimeInMillis() - now;

    // Convert to days
    final long days = millis / 86400000; // Precalculated (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) birthday - system time / milliseconds to get the value in days
    final long days30 = 2592000000L;

    if (millis <= days30 && checkFor16 == 16) {
        System.out.println("You are WITHIN 30 days of turning 16yrs old");
    }else if (millis > days30 && checkFor16 == 16){
        System.out.println("You are MORE THAN 30 DAYS OF BECOMING the age of 16");
    }else if(resultYear > 15) {
        System.out.println("You are OVER the age of 16");
    }else if(checkFor16 < 16 && millis == days30){
        System.out.println("You are BELOW the age of 16");
    }

    System.out.println("Left days to bday: " + days);

    //System.out.println("It will be       : " + dayOfTheWeek);
}
}
```

Now whenever I put in June 23 2016 - the condition is good. it means you are 15yrs old and 30 days until you turn 16. and with my project, this is supposed to be acceptable

Whenever i put the birthday to be anything before today's date June 22/06/2016 like example 30th, then the `day` returns something like for e.g Left days to bday: 341. While if i put 1st, july. it returns correctly "7 days until you turn 16". if you put a date that makes you 14yrs and below, it performs correctly.

If all that explanation is confusing for anyone, I am basically trying to get the following conditions: When you enter your birthday using the DatePicker:

Check for the following>

1. If you are 16, you ARE allowed in.
2. If you are above 16, you ARE allowed in.
3. If you 30 days until turning 16, you ARE allowed in.
4. If you are 31 days until you turn 16, then you are NOT allowed in, basically because you are 15.
5. If you are below the age of 16, meaning 15 and below, then you are NOT allowed in.

Can anyone please help me in figuring out what the problem is, and what to put for the conditionals, it can be simple toasts for now. the code that is performed in each of them will be created when i get this fixed and properly working. If not i cannot continue the project

**EDIT:**
I want

1. that if you put your birthday to be *any day* up to today's   date
   in the year 2000, from the date picker, it says a toast that you
   are 16, and **CAN** pass through.
2. And if you put a birthday that is 30 days(1 month) further from    today's date, then **you CAN** pass through too( i estimated that to
   be    July 24), because you will have 1 more month until you turn
   16.
3. And if you put your birthday that is 31 days or more further away from today's date( i estimated that to be    July 25+), then
   you **CANNOT** pass through, because you are 15 with more than 30
   days to your birthday.

I came up with this adjustment to my code, but it's not cutting it(what i want as stated above)

```
        final long daysOf30MilliSeconds = days30 / 86400000;

    if (days <= daysOf30MilliSeconds && checkFor16 == 16) {
        System.out.println("You are WITHIN 30 days of turning 16yrs old");
    }else if (days > daysOf30MilliSeconds && checkFor16 == 16 ){
        System.out.println("You are MORE THAN 30 DAYS OF BECOMING the age of 16");
    }else if(resultYear >= 16) {
        System.out.println("You are OVER the age of 16");
    }else if(resultYear < 16){
        System.out.println("You are BELOW the age of 16");
    }else if(resultYear == 16){
        System.out.println("You are 16, you can apply");
    }
```

All i need is the conditionals I think, can anybody provide the answer to the problem?

Comment: In daysRemaining(), you're comparing millis with days30.. millis can be +ve also and -ve also, and are in milliseconds.. whereas day30 is month..

Comment: With that statement, I was trying to compare millis(being the time the person has left to complete the age, if his age is further away from today's date) to 30 days in milliseconds. Was I wrong to do that, or should I use "days" instead of "millis"? Do I have any wrong concept?

Comment: I figured out the problem with what you were saying – user388229, and i made adjustments to the post above. please check it out

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method I use to extract age from birthday :

```
private String getAge(int year, int month, int day) {

    String age;
    int ageYear;
    int ageMonth;

    Calendar birth = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

    birth.set(year, month, day);

    ageYear = today.get(Calendar.YEAR) - birth.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    // if I am borned on february 1st, 2000 and we are on april 1st, 2000 :
    // 4 - 2 = 2 months
    // if I am borned on april 1st, 2000 and we are on february 1st, 2001
    // 12 - (4 - 2) = 10 months
    if (today.get(Calendar.MONTH) > birth.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {

        ageMonth = today.get(Calendar.MONTH) - birth.get(Calendar.MONTH);

    }

    else {

        ageMonth = 12 - birth.get(Calendar.MONTH) - today.get(Calendar.MONTH);

        ageYear--;

    }

    age = ageYear + " years and " + ageMonth + " months";

    return age;

}
```

*ageYear* and *ageMonth* could be class scoped properties and their values could be used in a conditionnal statement :

```
if (ageYear >= 16) then ...

if (ageYear == 15 && ageMonth == 11) then...

else then...
```

The returned age is for testing purpose only and can be either shown as a log or a toast.

Comment: So I am pretty naive to the whole fancy stuff you are saying with class scoped, but does it mean that my whole class of AgeCalculation can be replaced by your method?

Comment: No. It means that you have to declare variables outside the onCreate method and give them a value in your getAge method. getAge goes under onCreate and is called whenever the user selects his birthday.

Comment: Hey Alexandre martin, can you check the update i did today. Do you have any solutions for the problem now? I fixed a few problems already, just one is left now. Thanks

Comment: The source code I gave you should work... if not tell me the error you get please :) about the update, you only need the conditionals ?

Comment: It seems that that's all I would really need to proceed to my next step. Im still stuck on that. I just need to know what to put in my conditionals to have my requirements met, i.e. the things mentioned in the edit numbered 1-3

Comment: Conditionals you asked us to help you with are the same as the ones I sent you. It does exactly the same work : you can enter only if you are 16 or a month away from your 16th birthday, or older obviously. What is not working ?